# Is there a compact way to use `@I` notation in Org-Mode table / Spreadsheet?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

To get all the values between the first hline and the third you'd normally do `@I..@III`, however I'm already in my ninth line, and it's getting longer by the time I get to others.

Is there a more compact way to write it?

I already tried using `@I*8..@I*9` and it throws an error.

Comment: I don't think anything like that exists. Why do you need all those hlines? Maybe split the table into multiple tables?

Comment: @NickD Because I'm doing a transaction record that I want to export to LaTeX and to get the sum between each transaction I've been separating it with a hline to then refer to them with `@I`.  You're right, I'm relying too much on hlines. I got the same result i wanted by using the `@num` to refer the starting row and end row.